# How to skip dependent child destroy callback in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, activemodel

I have a User model with the following association:

```
has_many :brands, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :owner
```

But there are some users, which have a null master_id field that I don't want to call the destroy callback on his brands association. Is it possible?

I tried:

```
user.destroy
user.delete
```

But I couldn't skip the destroy callback on his brands association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing that worked for me with Mongoid 4 was:

```
class Bar
  has_many :foos, depedent: :delete
end

bar.assign_attributes foos: nil 
bar.save # Doesn't call the relation callback above

# All the below call the relation callback
bar.foos.delete_all 
bar.foos = []
bar.foos = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You could skip `dependent: :destroy` by using a `before_destroy` callback as follows:

```
# app/models/user.rb

has_many :brands, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :owner
before_destroy :prevent_destroy, prepend: true

private

def prevent_destroy
  return false if self.master_id.nil?
end
```

See, further reference on [Cancelling callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).  With the above setup, if the user's `master_id` is `nil` then `before_destroy` returns `false` which prevents the `dependent: :destroy` from executing.

Comment: I'm using Mongoid, it has a lot of common with ActiveRecord but it seems this solution do not work with it.